# ANTLR grammar file: does not mark errors in the grammar file

Tags: parsing, antlr3

I have only started working with ANTLR, it is working fine 
the problem i am having is that when i build the project it does not see or mark errors in the grammar file, and it builds successfully (only for the first time then it does nothing until i change a bit in the grammar). I know there are errors in the grammar file, which it detects if i test the interpreter. i am using ANTLR  3.5.2 with eclipse Helios.
anyone knows how to fix it to mark the errors ?
this is a simple code which has errors but it builds successfully.

```
grammar XL;
options {
  language = Java;
}

@header {
  package com.java.antlr3.test1;
}

@lexer::header {
  package com.java.antlr3.test1;
}

program 
    :   'program' IDENT '='
        (constant | variable)* 
        'begin'
        statement*
        'end' IDENT '.'
    ;

constant 
    :   'constant' IDENT ':' type ':=' expression ';'
    ;

variable 
    : 'var' IDENT(',' IDENT)* ':' type (':=' expression)* ';'
    ;

type 
    : 
        'Integer'
    ;

statement 
    :   assignmentStatement 
    |   ifStatement
    |   loopStatement 
    |   exitStatement
    ;

assignmentStatement 
    :   IDENT ':=' INTEGER ';'
    ;


INTEGER : '0'..'9'+;
IDENT : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*;
WS : (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r'|'\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to ANTLR4? I just put your grammar through it locally and it kicked up errors.

Comment: @TML, thanks for your reply, i have not tried upgrading yet, but i just saw that ANTLR4 IDE only supports Eclipse Kepler, and because I am working on other plugins which only work on Helios i am using Eclipse Helios
i will give it a go